# How to send HTTP response in Json format in Generic Class Views [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have sub-classed Generic DetailView class in `views.py` and trying to figure out a way to return data in JSON format based on an argument received in the url. Here's what I have tried doing...

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.http import JsonResponse    

class ExtendedView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = StorageModel
    template_name='posts.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(HacksViewPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if bool(self.request.GET):
            data__ = JsonForm(request.GET)
            if data__.is_valid():
                json = data__.cleaned_data['json']
                if json == 'true':
                    return JsonResponse({'data': 'data'})
        return data
```

But this gave me `TypeError` as it should be:

```
TypeError at /category/extended-slug/
context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.
```

The url that activates the `ExtendedView` class is:

```
/category/extended-slug?json=true
```

So, the question is how could i send data in JSON Format from a Generic View Class and are there any better ways of acheiving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you patch it at the wrong level. The `get_context_data` is used by the `get` function to render it. As a result, the `get_context_data` object has *no* control about what is done with the result, in order to construct a server response,

You can however patch the `get(..)` function like:

```
class ExtendedView(DetailView):

    """A base view for displaying a single object."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        data = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        if self.request.GET:
            data__ = JsonForm(request.GET)
            if data__.is_valid():
                json = data__.cleaned_data['json']
                if json == 'true':
                    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
        return self.render_to_response(data)
```

The same holds for `post`, `put`, and other requests.

If we take a look at the [`DetailView` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L103) we see:

> ```
> class BaseDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
>     """A base view for displaying a single object."""
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         self.object = self.get_object()
>         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

Hence the `get(..)` calls the `get_context_data(..)` function. But it does *not* immediately returns the result, it wraps it into a *rendered* response.

Comment: Exactly, what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a `JsonResponse` inside the `get_context_data` method. The `get_context_data` method allows you to send extra information (context) to the template and is expected to return a `dict`, not a `JsonResponse`.

If you want to return a `JsonResponse`, do that in the `get` or `post` method of your class.